# adding an application into the search computer menu

Tags: 14.04, shortcuts

I am currently using ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS.  I just installed it and I searched up by pressing `Alt+F2` I am able to search the computer for programs / files / folders but somehow I installed webstorm and it's not searchable (Maybe because the program was only extracted instead of a real installation such as FileZilla which is already available to be searched when I typed in FileZilla)

Is there a way I can add webstorm into the search? (not even sure which tags I should add this into)

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: when I download as linux it's just a .tag.az file by extracting it I use terminal to go into the `webstorm/bin/webstom.sh` I followed a post in here to run something like `chmod -x webstorm.sh` then `./webstorm.sh` to start the program

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to open this program, when searching it with the dash, it is advisable to add a desktop launcher to it as described here:

[How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)